# Where can I find the _sre.py python built-in module?

Tags: python, regex

I am studying the  python regular expression (`re.py`) source code.

In `re.py` they imported the module `sre_compile`:

```
import sre_compile
```

and I look at the module sre_compile there they imported the module `_sre`  in the line 13

```
import _sre, sys
```

I searched for the module `_sre.py` but I could not find it anywhere, I even tried to
locate `_sre.py` in my shell.

In the end I tried to locate it with the python interpreter. I imported `_sre` and I was trying to look for the `__file__` attribute of `_sre` but it gave me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

Where can I find the `_sre` module source code?

Comment: Voted to reopen. This question isn't asking for a recommendation or a link; it's specifically asking where `_sre` exists *within the Python source code*. (And there's a specific reason they need help finding it.)

Comment: I don't see how this question fails to describe an unambiguous technical problem. I had the same question, came here for an answer. On top of which my system doesn't contain any files with the substring `_sre` (be it `_sre.c` or otherwise), so the existing answer seems incomplete. Vote to reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_sre` is the C-extension that implements most of the `re` module functionality. C-extensions usually do not have a `__file__` attribute.

As such you are looking for the [`_sre.c` source file](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_sre.c) instead.

Comment: Is that written in language C?

Comment: Yes, that's written in C.

Comment: When I perform  import _sre  in python interpreter    what file  would be imported.

Comment: In this case `_sre` is a built-in module; it's compiled into the Python binary. It's one of several exceptions; `posix`, `errno`, `pwd`, `_codecs`, `_weakref` and `zipimport` being the others.

Comment: You mean to say  it is  (dot).pyd file  or  (dot).so file

Comment: It is neither, it is part of the Python binary. *other* C-extension modules are usually loaded from a `.so` or `.dll` or similar file, yes.