# How do I access classes and get a dir() of available actions?

Tags: python

I have been trying to get access to available functions for a Match Object from re.search. I am looking for a way to do that similar to how I could do dir(str) and I can find .replace.

This is my dir() for the re module and some of the things I have tried:

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search('x', 'x')
>>> dir(re)
['DEBUG', 'DOTALL', 'I', 'IGNORECASE', 'L', 'LOCALE', 'M', 'MULTILINE', 
'S', 'Scanner', 'T', 'TEMPLATE', 'U', 'UNICODE', 'VERBOSE', 'X', 
'_MAXCACHE', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', 
'__package__', '__version__', '_alphanum', '_cache', '_cache_repl', 
'_compile', '_compile_repl', '_expand', '_locale', '_pattern_type', 
'_pickle', '_subx', 'compile', 'copy_reg', 'error', 'escape', 'findall', 
'finditer', 'match', 'purge', 'search', 'split', 'sre_compile', 
'sre_parse', 'sub', 'subn', 'sys', 'template']
```

I want to get to this menu without having to create the Match Object:

```
>>> dir(m)
['__class__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', 
'__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', 
'__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', 
'__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'end', 'endpos', 'expand', 'group', 
'groupdict', 'groups', 'lastgroup', 'lastindex', 'pos', 're', 'regs', 
'span', 'start', 'string']
```

Is there a way to go from dir(m) and be able to find out how to go up a level? That way I can trace my way back to the module and functions. Like if I was to do dir(re.search.func_dict), how can I find out what I need to type into dir() to get back a list that included func_dict()?

```
>>> dir(re.Match)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Match'
```

I see this thing about _sre.SRE._Match but how do I found out where that lives so I can get more information on it?

```
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 'm': <_sre.SRE_Match 
object at 0xb7b0d8a8>, '__package__': None, 're': <module 're' from 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/re.pyc'>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
```

I have tried to use the inspect function, but the only function that gives me any info is inspect.getmembers(re) but it's just a ton of stuff I don't understand.

I am a complete newbie following a learn as you program course and I have no bases knowledge in Python other than some programs I have written. I have been trying to use dir() and help() a lot to learn. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: `dir(re.Match)` won't work because `match` is _lowercase_. It's a typo. Works fine with `dir(re.match)`

Comment: I don't want the function re.match, I was trying to get to a Match object I guess following someone else's advice for a similar problem. I guess I meant more re.MatchObject

Comment: I've just seen that advice and am about to comment on it

Comment: There is a boring old method to find this info - it’s called reading the documentation, e.g. for Python 2.7 https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html. Reading documentation is a good habit to get into because you will often learn about more than the particular thing you are looking for. Also it is quicker - you will waste a lot less of your valuable time, and ours - and you get less sarcasm than when asking questions here which are covered by widely accessible and totallu searchable documentation which can easily be located on a popular search engine and some carefully selected search terms.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the online documentation?

Comment: I have used the documentation and it is very valuable I agree. However if possible, I'd like to be independent of needing the internet every time. I spent hours scouring for the answer to this question without success. The Match Object and re documentation is definitely good info, but I think to understand a lot of it I need a plethora of python fundamentals that would take a long time and me off course. I just want to be able to get by with dir() as I'm learning. I don't know why I chose to obsess over this but I'll be happy to be done with it and move on lol.

Comment: The short answer is that you cannot in this particular example without creating the object. `_sre.SRE_Match` is not a Python class. It is defined in C (in cpython, of course) only, so there's no introspection available to Python on the class itself, only on the object after it is built.

Comment: Can you create a SRE_Match object without using an re function? I try importing and inspecting _sre and it has barely anything I can see to use in it

Comment: Err ‘independent of the internet’ - did I die and go to a strange world where StackOverflow is not on the internet?

Comment: lol, yes it is the internet, but I don't have the greatest memory, and there are times I don't have internet access. So I would like to be able to get the information I need without having to go find internet. I suppose I can try get a pdf of the python documentation. But either way it wouldn't/didn't help me in this case. At least I haven't learned where in the python documentation it said how and where to explore Match Objects, just what they "are" and "do". It definitely didn't tell me anywhere that they're stored in a C-file. This is a learning process for me, an I do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3.7, `re.Match` is the type of the objects returned by `re.match`. See [bpo30397](https://bugs.python.org/issue30397).

In previous versions, `re.Match` is not defined. If you wanted a reference to the type of match objects you could get it with

```
Match = type(re.match('',''))
```

You can use `dir` on either the `Match` type or on a match object to list its attributes and methods.

Comment: That makes sense, I like how the ink says "that represent the types of compiled regular expression objects and match objects". That is essentially what I was searching for and it was driving me nuts that I could use inspect and gc and globals() and kept seeing _sre_SRE_Match object over and over again and in errors, but I could never pinpoint where these mystical objects are. I still don't know much about objects too so I figured that was it. I noticed when I did help(m), where m is my created match, it would say object at the top and talk about the class. I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest thing I have gotten so far:

```
>>> import re, inspect

>>> inspect.getmembers(re,inspect.isclass)
[('Scanner', <class re.Scanner at 0xb7b7bcec>), ('_pattern_type', <type 
'_sre.SRE_Pattern'>), ('error', <class 'sre_constants.error'>)]

>>> from re import _pattern_type

>>> dir(_pattern_type)
['__class__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', 
'__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', 
'__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'findall', 
'finditer', 'flags', 'groupindex', 'groups', 'match', 'pattern', 'scanner', 'search', 
'split', 'sub', 'subn']
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently _sre is a C-extension so SRE_Match is defined within this C-file

[Where can I find the _sre.py python built-in module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968462/where-can-i-find-the-sre-py-python-built-in-module)

https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_sre.c